# If $P$ is self-adjoint, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P\in \mathbb{B}(H)$ be a projection (i.e., $P^2=P$). Prove that if $P$ is self-adjoint, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Here our definition of orthogonal projection is as follows:

> The orthogonal projection $P_L$ of some space $X$ onto some subspace $L$ is defined in such a way that $P_Lx=y$ where $x= y + y'$ for $y \in L$ and $y'\in L^{\perp}$.

My proof is as follows.

Claim: $ker P \perp Im P$.

Indeed, for any $x\in Ker P, y\in Im P$, there is $u\in H$ so that $Pu=y$:
$$
(x,y)=(x, Pu)=(P^*x, u)=(Px,u)=0
$$

Then let $L:=Im P$. For any $x\in H$ there is unique $y\in L$ and $z\in L^{\perp}$ so that $$
x=y+z
$$

Note that for any $y\in L$, we have $Py=y$. (Indeed, there is $u$ so that $Pu=y$, then $Py=P^2u=Pu=y$.

Then
$$
(Px-y, Px-y)=(Px-Py, Px-Pu)=(x-y, P^*P(x-y))=(x-y, P(Px-Py))=0
$$
where $x-y\in L^{\perp}$ and $P(Px-Py)\in Im P=L$.

Thus, $Px=y$. Hence, $P=P_L$. **[Question: Does it make sense?]**

Claim: $Im P$ is closed subspace of $H$.

Take $x_n\in ImP$ so that $x_n\in x$ in $H$. Then there is $y_n$ so that $P(y_n)=x_n$,
$$
x=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(y_n)=P(\lim x_n)=P(x)
$$
Then $x\in ImP$.

Comment: Orthogonal projections have closed range. Your definition does not agree with the usual one. You did not prove that the image of $P$ is a closed subspace.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh! Thank you! Except for adding proof of $Im P$ is closed, everything looks good?

Comment: @Hermi May I ask why $x-u \in  L^{\perp}$ ?

Comment: @Tri That is a typo. Here I want to say $y=Py$. Then $x-y=z\in L^\perp$.